# Using a shell script but it fails with spaces on directory or name

Tags: linux, shell, script

I'm relatively new to Linux script and I'm having an issue with one I'm trying to use when there are spaces in the directory name or file name. The script shrinks PDF files so that i can put them in an e-mail.

```
gs  -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER \
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
    -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 \
    -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen \
    -dEmbedAllFonts=true \
    -dSubsetFonts=true \
    -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
    -dColorImageResolution=72 \
    -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
    -dGrayImageResolution=72 \
    -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
    -dMonoImageResolution=72 \
    -sOutputFile=Compressed$1 \
     "$1"
```

so I use the command

```
find * -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec sudo sh ~/shrinkpdf.sh {} \;
```

It will work on the PDF in the same folder that has no spaces in it, but whenit tries to access the folders within that have spaces it errors and created a file using only the first word of the folder name.

How can I get this to accept files and folders with spaces in the names?

Thanks from a user who is Shell Script Challenged,

Comment: Aside from my answer... I generally try to avoid the situation of having filenames that confuse the shell. You can use a utility like `gprenamer` to batch-rename your files (replace one or more spaces with _, for example). That's my preferred solution, because many programs mistakenly assume that your filenames are sane and safe.

Comment: Thank you very much. It appears to be working! I did not think i was going to need to create a script to shrink the PDF's. I was hoping my scanning software would do it be default. Ill remember this for next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are quoting one of the $1 's but not the other. If your path contains spaces, quoting is essential. To be safe, it's best to assume that every path a script receives contains problematic characters, and quote every path.

Here's my suggestion:

```
gs  -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER \
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
    -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 \
    -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen \
    -dEmbedAllFonts=true \
    -dSubsetFonts=true \
    -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
    -dColorImageResolution=72 \
    -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
    -dGrayImageResolution=72 \
    -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
    -dMonoImageResolution=72 \
    "-sOutputFile=Compressed$1" \
    "$1"
```

In case you are wondering, it's fine to quote options like this; it's no different from quoting other kinds of arguments. `gs -q`  and `gs "-q"` look exactly the same to gs when gs receives them.

We just use them here to make sure the entire path is made part of the `-sOutputFile` option , rather than what was previously the case: the fragment before the space was correctly assigned to the option argument, and the fragment after the space was an independent argument, that `gs` may well have treated as if it were the input file argument.